# Deleted Win7 partition of 263GB. How to get Ubuntu 12.04 to utilize that space?

Tags: partitioning

Win7 had a lot of problems so I finally got disgusted with it and deleted the entire partition. No I have 263 GB of unused HDD. How can I make Ubuntu use it? I don't know how to extend Ubuntus' partition to include it!

Answer (score 2):

If you have already deleted the space and it is unallocated, boot to the Ubuntu live CD and run `GParted` which will allow you to expand your partition, create a new one, etc.

Comment: If not running Windows I would not make it a NTFS partition, but I would just create a ext4 data partition. Then you can mount that in your system. Moving partitions around can take a while and may  cause issues if interrupted for any reason. But if creating new data partition you will need to set ownership & permissions to easily use it.

Comment: Thank you. I still have the disk but it says: It's an older version. Either way, I'll give it a shot or make a new disk with an up-dated version. Thank you again. Have a good weekend.

Comment: Could very well happen if you installed say 12.04 and did a distro upgrade or something similar. But yea you are on the right path burn a newer dvd and use GParted from a live session.